# Pull a specific frame at current time using VLC

Tags: linux, video, shell, python, vlc-media-player

I am trying to create any sort of command in python or shell to pull one specific frame from a video that is being played or streamed on vlc.

Imagine a scenario where I have a video file, I open it on VLC and I click play. I pull the first frame I encounter in python or using a shell command, do some processing, and when the processing is done, I capture another frame at the exact time that the video has reached.

Honestly, if I can even get VLC to provide for me the current "time" of a video I am playing (how many hours:minutes:seconds or whatever we have gone through in the movie), that would do and I can use ffmpeg.

I am running linux 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I can even get VLC to provide for me the current "time" of a video I am playing…

This can be done. VLC provides many interfaces. Let's use telnet.

---

#### Step 1: enabling telnet in VLC

One-time on-demand method:

```
vlc --extraintf telnet --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password "foobar" video_file_to_play.avi
```

Or permanent configuration. Run VLC, *Tools* -> *Preferences* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), then:

[image: config1]

and

[image: config2]

Note: this permanent method requires you to restart VLC.

---

#### Step 2: testing

Now you can control VLC with telnet. Type the right password when prompted. Example:

```
$ telnet localhost 4212
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax
Password: 
Welcome, Master
> get_time
30
>
```

As you can see, the command to retrieve current playing time is `get_time`. Type `help` to learn more VLC commands, `quit` to quit. Maybe you will find `snapshot` useful.

---

#### Step 3: using in a script

Quite a simple pipe. Here I use `nc` instead of `telnet` (and `foobar` is my password, use yours):

```
printf '%s\n' "foobar" "get_time" | nc localhost 4212
```

My VLC returns:

> ```
> VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax
> Password: ����
> Welcome, Master
> 87
> > Bye-bye!
> ```

so I use `head` and `tail` to extract the relevant line only:

```
printf '%s\n' "foobar" "get_time" | nc localhost 4212 | head -n 4 | tail -n 1
```

Unfortunately the time resolution is 1 second. I haven't found a command to retrieve the current frame number or so.